# JS/Jquery set autosize width and height without refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have `div` on bootstrap 3, which should show 4 columns for each row. But pictures height and width are different, therefore pictures are not located sequencly 4 items for each row. I want to add JS to autosize pictures aspect to ratio and make it work with js refresh without page refresh. Here is my code and it is not working right, please help me with this.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<?php
while(contion)                //WHILE LOOP
{
?>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 pull-right">
  <img src="<?php echo selectphoto($photoid, 7, 0); ?>" class="img-responsive" ?>">
  <!-----------------SCRIPT HERE CUZ OF WHILE LOOP TO BE ABLE GET ID OF PICTURES---------------------->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function callback() {
      var w = window.innerWidth;
      var h = window.innerHeight;

      if (w > 767) {

        target = document.getElementById('picturesize<?php echo $photoid ?>');
        target.style.width = ((w) / 5.81) + 'px';
        target.style.height = (((w) / 5.81) / 1.5) + 'px';
      } else {
        target.style.width = (w / 2.4) + 'px';
        target.style.height = (w / 2.4) / 1.5) + 'px';
    }
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize', callback);

    callback();
  </script>
  <!-----------------END OF JS---------------------->
</div>
<?php
}               //END OF WHILE LOOP
?>
```

**JS CODE out of div**

```js
 function callback() {
      var w = window.innerWidth;
      var h = window.innerHeight;

      if (w > 767) {

        target = document.getElementById('picturesize<?php echo $photoid ?>');
        target.style.width = ((w) / 5.81) + 'px';
        target.style.height = (((w) / 5.81) / 1.5) + 'px';
      } else {
        target.style.width = (w / 2.4) + 'px';
        target.style.height = (w / 2.4) / 1.5) + 'px';
    }
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize', callback);

    callback();
```

Comment: Do you have a wireframe for your page? I believe that it is possible to do with html and css.

Comment: @Bsalex but with css i will not be able set it automaticaly udpdate width and height for browser width change. It is only possible with js or jquery

Comment: Modern markup techniques provide a lot of tools for this type of tasks. Flexbox, Grid, CSS `background-size` and `object-fit`, media query.

Comment: If you really need to use JS - also look at https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/resizeobserver